# Using dompdf with Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dompdf

Before I started using Zend Framework, I simply installed dompdf in a directory and was able to call PDF downloads through a URL, similar to this:

`http://*url*dompdf/dompdf.php?base_path=**path**&name=**name**`

I thought I'd try and be clever and just insert dompdf into the Zend /public directory.  But then I realized it wasn't going to properly call the classes that dompdf uses, such as DOMPDF_Exception, etc.

Is there a way around this? I really have no idea how to integrate the two, and they have to be accessible by URL (as seen above)

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help you? http://www.dashinteractive.net/dompdf/index.php?v=3043395

Comment: I don't think so -- that looks like it's actually using dompdf inside a controller, whereas I want it to just render a PDF through the dompdf.php URL.

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't use ZF, but it seems that anything in the public directory won't result in the bootstrap being called, and so dompdf's autoloader will work. Need someone with ZF knowledge to chime in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add both by doing the following.

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
require_once('Zend/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$load = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$load->pushAutoloader('DOMPDF_autoload','');
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using DOMPDF w/ Zend by simply putting the dompdf folder in /library/dompdf.  In my application.ini I have the following line:

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
```

I include the library by doing:

```
require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
```

Then I invoke by doing:

```
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($pdfLayout);
  $dompdf->render();
  $pdfOutput = $dompdf->output();
```

Works like a charm!